# Ubuntu 12.04 - Install newer libqtwebkit4 instead 2.2.1 for ScudCloud

Tags: 12.04, ppa, qt

I am trying to install [ScudCloud](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/linux-loving-slack-users-heres-an-app-for-you/), but it requires `libqtwebkit4` version 2.3.2 or greater.

Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 12.04 the latest version still remains in 2.2.1.

Is there a PPA or an alternative way to update `libqtwebkit4` to a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in [ScudCloud's Github](https://github.com/raelgc/scudcloud) page:

Since you do:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/scudcloud
```

Don't update and/or try do install ScudCloud. Instead, add these PPA's to solve the `libqtwebkit4` incompatibility:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:immerrr-k/qtwebkit4-backport
```

Then, update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scudcloud
```